# Can "other story" work without a definite article (for a title)?

Tags: expressions, definite-articles

As far as I know, “Other story” is an expression often used in conjunction with the definite article "the," as in "the other story goes" or "the other story says". In some cases I've seen it used without "the", as in "it's a whole other story," but can it be used in a title without "the" before it, or as the name of a collective like "other story collective"?

Comment: We're increasing seeing / hearing [*whole **nother** story*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whole+nother+story&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhole%20nother%20story%3B%2Cc0) in recent decades. Kinda the opposite of ***naranja*** losing that initial /n/ (from the article ***an***) to become ***orange***.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'other story' on its own would mean. Other than what? You can, of course, use the indefinite article if you wish.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or "a napron" becoming "an apron".

Comment: *Can “other story” work without a definite article (for a title)?* Yes, but it  must be capitalised "Other Story". Often a significance of the title of a book, poem, film, etc., is not obvious until the audience has read/seen quite a lot of it. (In Herman Melville's "Moby Dick" - the name is not mentioned until chapter 36.) Grammatically, the guidance for titles, etc., is not the same as for "normal" English.

Comment: In "it's a whole other story" "a" is the article.

Comment: The issue is not "other"; it is that many titles tend to start with "the",—it makes the book seem definitive (and the author smart, somehow)—and so, "Other Stories Collective" sounds a bit lackluster.

Comment: You can certainly use it without a title, but then it's not clear whether it means *the other story* or *another story* or something else.

Comment: Lots of titles don't start with "The". Would "Little Women" be more popular if it was called "The Little Women"? Or "Lyrical Ballads", Joe Orton's "Loot", "Animal Farm", "Treasure Island", "Apocalypse Now", "Death in Venice"...

Answer (score 1):

> can [other story] be used in a title without "the" before it?

Yes.

Such as in:

1. *What Other Story?*
2. *Her Other Story*
3. *Other Story, Morning Glory*
4. *Wild and Gory Other Story*
5. *My Brother’s Other Story*

> can [other story] be used as…the name of a collective like "other story collective"?

Yes.

Such as in:

1. Select Other Story Collective
2. Other Story Detective Collective
3. Your Boring Other Story Collective
4. First Other Story Collective
5. California Other Story Collective

Answer (score -2):

A title can be or include anything you like. I don't think this would be understood as you hope without the *the* you mention.

From  "it's a whole other story," we can see that it's *a* other story, meaning *another* story altogether. Here the article is so expected it has become part of the [new] word, *an other*.